# Exists any HTML form widget that is a always-visible list selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, widget

I need an HTML widget to be used on a website that's using the Twitter Bootstrap framework. I think that this widget must already exist, but I don't know which is the name of this widget...

It's like the "Bootstrap Multiselect" (https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) widget, but without being dropdown: I need the options box always visible. More or less like this screenshot: https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/raw/master/example.png?raw=true

So, the question is really easy: anyone knows if a widget like this already exists? If so, what's it's name?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using "Bootstrap Multiselect" but where you modify "bootstrap-multiselect.js" so that it does not close/remove/destroy the options? You might also want to change the layout but that's up to you.

(It won't allow me to comment so my only option is to answer.)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible... Keep in mind that "Bootstrap Multiselect" is based on a "select" widget, always drawn by the navigator as a drop-down widget, and I need an always-shown widget (like an "iframe" with some checkboxes inside)...

Comment: This may seem like a silly question, but why would you want a select that's not really a select? The purpose of a select is to temporarily present the user with multiple options and then hide them when the user has made his choices. To me it seem like you just want a page loaded in an iframe where you can select multiple checkboxes. If that is the case then all you need is an ordinary set of divs and checkboxes and style them like you like them to look like. What extra features would you like?

Comment: I don't think that this is a silly question. I don't know if you have ever done Windows or Mac desktop development, but the widget I'm asking for is a typical UI element on these systems... And no, it isn't as easy as creating a div and put some checkboxes inside it. But, if I can't find any widget like this, I'll create it from scratch.

Comment: I made a simple version of the functionality. Feel free to modify it if you can use it and feel free to ask me questions. It could definitely use some improvements and styling. I don't have much experience with jsfiddle so I placed everything in the HTML-container. The example is located here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmwo5jcj/